# Django ValueError for deleted fields when running migrations

Tags: django, django-models

My `models.py` file is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from random import randint

# Create your models here.
class File(models.Model):
    fileName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    dateUploaded = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    doc = models.FileField(default = None)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length = 6, default = randint(100000000, 999999999), unique = True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I used to have `code = models.CharField(default = 'A13S34', max_length = 6, unique = True` but it kept giving the error `ValueError: Field 'code' expected a number but got '236E96'.` Thus, I replaced it with the serial field.

However, now when I try to `makemigrations` and `migrate`, I get the same error `ValueError: Field 'code' expected a number but got '236E96'.` What can I do when I no longer even have the code field?

Comment: Is your migration containing `code` field removal last one? It looks like there is another migration which hasn't been ran before migration which removes `code` field

Comment: can you show how does the table really look like in DB? (`show table <table_name>` in MySQL or `\d <table_name>` in PgSQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @asiniy has mentioned, the previous migration is still there. You may:

1. Delete the previous (or all) migration file from '/migrations' folder
2. Run migrations and migrate.

If there are still errors, you may consider clear all models in DB by

1. Comment out all your model in models.py
2. Run migrations and migrate
3. Add back the correct models and redo the migration and migrate